# GUI not showing on my screen

Tags: java, swing, constructor, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have made GUIs run on my computer before, but with this program I wanted to try to implement GridBag so I could make a simple game. I don't have a clue why it isn't running. This is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagTest extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new GridBagTest();
    }

    public void GridBagTest(){
        JButton atk, mag, fort, pot1, pot2, flee;
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("FightQuest"); 
        gameFrame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
        gameFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);

        atk = new JButton("Strike");
        mag = new JButton("Magic");
        fort = new JButton("Fortify");
        pot1 = new JButton("Potion 1");
        pot2 = new JButton("Potion 2");
        flee = new JButton("Flee");
        addItem(gamePanel, atk, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, mag, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, fort, 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot1, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, flee, 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);

    }

    private void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align){
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this makes any difference, but I got most of this code from a Java reference book for Java 6 even though I'm running Java 7 since it was all my school had. I am also doing all my code on the XFCE operating system.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: I have no clue how to make this any shorter, removing stuff from the code doesn't make the GUI appear. I need other people to tell me how to shorten or elongate the code.

Comment: Well congratulations, you totally grasp 1 out of 4 of the things that make an SSCCE.  Now look at ***the other 3.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
public void GridBagTest()
```

to

```
public GridBagTest()
```

Constructor doesn't have return type. Also you should call `pack()` and `setVisible(true)` to size and show components after adding them to the container.

Also note that extending is not necessary in this case.

Change

```
public class GridBagTest extends JFrame
```

to

```
public class GridBagTest{
```

Changes shows in code:

```
public class GridBagTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GridBagTest();
            }
        });
    }

    public GridBagTest(){
        JButton atk, mag, fort, pot1, pot2, flee;
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("FightQuest"); 
        gameFrame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
        gameFrame.setSize(800, 600);


        atk = new JButton("Strike");
        mag = new JButton("Magic");
        fort = new JButton("Fortify");
        pot1 = new JButton("Potion 1");
        pot2 = new JButton("Potion 2");
        flee = new JButton("Flee");
        addItem(gamePanel, atk, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, mag, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, fort, 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot1, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, flee, 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align){
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

And you get your output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but your calls to `gameFrame.setSize(800, 600);` and `gameFrame.pack();` seem to be conflicting, as `pack()` will re-set the size according to the current contents of the frame.  (Which at the point you call `pack()`, is nothing)

By the way, you should also create and update your Swing components on the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: I removed the pack() from my code, but that didn't make the GUI appear.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I look for when reviewing problems like this is how the application is launched. Please notice that [you are not properly launching your GUI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). You should be making sure that the GUI is launched on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).

Here is an example of how to launch your specific GUI.

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478125/gui-not-showing-on-my-screen/20478279#20478279
 */
public class Q20478125 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Q20478125();
            }
        });
    }

    public Q20478125() {
        JButton atk, mag, fort, pot1, pot2, flee;
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
        gamePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("FightQuest");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);

        atk = new JButton("Strike");
        mag = new JButton("Magic");
        fort = new JButton("Fortify");
        pot1 = new JButton("Potion 1");
        pot2 = new JButton("Potion 2");
        flee = new JButton("Flee");
        addItem(gamePanel, atk, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, mag, 1, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, fort, 2, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot1, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST);
        addItem(gamePanel, pot2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTH);
        addItem(gamePanel, flee, 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST);

    }

    private void addItem(JPanel p, JComponent c, int x, int y, int width, int height, int align) {
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gc.gridx = x;
        gc.gridy = y;
        gc.gridwidth = width;
        gc.gridheight = height;
        gc.weightx = 100.0;
        gc.weighty = 100.0;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gc.anchor = align;
        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        p.add(c, gc);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a psudo constructor for placing `void` before `GridBagTest()` which specifies that `GridBagTest()` is a function not a constructor. So call:

```
new GridBagTest().GridBagTest();
```

inside the main function. Which obviously you should not do: rather remove the return type `void`:

```
public GridBagTest(){ //<--- void is removed


        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("FightQuest"); 
        // other code
}
```

However, always start your program from the EDT by submitting it to EventQueue using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

               new GridBagTest();
            }
        });
```